# How to hide qtip in fullcalendar?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, qtip

this is my code of fullcalendar

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({ 
                      ..... 
            eventRender: function(event, element) {

                  element.bind('dblclick', function() {
                      $('#wrap').hide();
                      $('#inserimento').show();
                  });
                  element.qtip({
                        content: {
                             title: {
                                text: event.title,
                                button: 'X'
                             },
                             text: '<b>Ore: </b>' + event.ore + '<br />' +'<b>Note spese: </b>' + event.spese + '<br /><br />' +
                                   '<a href="javascript:elimina(\'' + event.id + '\' )">Elimina</a>'
                          }
     ..... 

    });
```

This javascipt's function remove the event:

```
function elimina(value){
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar("removeEvents",  value);
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar("rerenderEvents");

}
```

The function remove the event in fullCalendar, but the relative qtip remains. I don't know how to hide/remove the qTip. Could u help me?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727504/qtip-jquery-plug-in-how-can-i-remove-all-qtips-in-my-page. This discussion can help you